# How to finish a dungeon level?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

How do I finish a dungeon level? Am I obliged to kill all the monsters or are there other options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By killing the monster(s) that is level 10. The level should register as completed, and you will be free to retire your character.

Comment: This monster is both named, and has, for lack of better term, "flavor text" both on its info and a "taunt" when you first uncover him.